# no such column sqlite selectquery

Tags: python, sqlite, bottle

I'm using a select query to get the user details from an sqlite databse from a username for verification of login details using the following code:

```
    @post('/login/attempt')
    def processLogin():
        submittedUsername = request.forms.get("Username")
        submittedPassword = request.forms.get("Password")
        data = c.execute("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Users.username = 
                         {}".format(submittedUsername)).fetchone()
```

I get the error `OperationalError ('no such column: janedoe')`
janedoe is the username I've been putting in to the form.

I don't understand why this would be looking for a column with that name. As far as I understand this should be looking for a row in which the value in the username column is "janedoe".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your query is correct, I think what you are trying to do is :

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=?', (submittedUsername,)).fetchone()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Don't the parameters need to be wrapped in a tuple?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I've tried using this method of string manipulation and it seems to work. (although the syntax is slightly different than in your reply: ```data = c.execute("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Users.username = ?", (submittedUsername,)).fetchone()```, importantly the submittedUsername needs to be in brackets, and needs the extra comma after as that format of replacement expects a tuple

Comment: @AKX yes indeed